# Unsubscribed client from server when network connection lost in action cable

Tags: actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have implemented action cable with Rails 5.1.1 and Ruby 2.3.1. Everything works fine but when client lost network connectivity then disconnected method is getting called at client side but how server will identify connection lost at client. Is there any way for getting acknowledged when client loses the connection?

I want to implement simple thing when client lost connection then I want to call unsubscribed method at server.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. If you close connection properly you should be notified. Otherwise you will be notified when tcp connection closes which may take several minutes or never if server restarts.